# Codeigniter Index Controller routing problem

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a index controller name Index.php under directory /system/application/controller/

and i have set the rules of .htacesss

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(include||index.php|images|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

and i turn $route['default_controller'] = "index";

and i config $config['index_page'] = "";

and i have a index action in my controller

when i access http://domain/index/index/en will have 404

when i access http://domain/index/index/index/en will be fine

and i try to echo $this->uri->segments in Libraries/Router.php

find that if i request with index/index/en, it return only index and en

if i request index/index/index/en it return index, index and en,

as ci route logic the first segment is the controller name and second is the action

can it be solve???? just dont want too long url in home page

Comment: what happens if you access a controller **not** called "index"?

Comment: it was fine, but i dont want to change rather than index client dont like home or main, it must be index

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html) actually states that a controller can't be named 'index' because it's a reserved word.

If you goal is to get pretty URL's you should leave the default controller as it was originally and leave the $config["index_page"] variable empty.

Then create this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

That would make CI and you a happy couple...

Comment: THX very much,  just a little question in document "Do not name your controller functions any of these: eg　index", but i only name the controller with index, and why there is no problem for any controller has a function called index?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the interpretation of the document; it's not your controllers functions you can't name 'index'. Just the controller class name. The reason for this should be clear when reading the documentation for controller functions at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html