# Codeigniter post request blank

Tags: php, codeigniter

i've been doing a post request from my view, but the controller doesn't receive the form values.

**view**:

```
       <form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url('index/busca_vaga/'); ?>" id="busca_form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="busca" placeholder="Buscar um cargo / setor / palavras-chave"/>
                <i class="ti-time"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-search-icon" id="realiza_busca"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**Controller**:

```
public function busca_vaga() {
        print_r($_POST);exit;
}
```

**Result**:
Array ( )

What is going on?

Comment: base_url() not defined?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url

Comment: after @Vickel comment verified (base_url is defined) then use https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: does index is a controller ? what is your controller name?

Comment: Base_url was set.

Comment: global_xss_filtering is enable and my controller name is Index.

Comment: @DiegoRodriguesCampos i think index is reserved name for controller try to use other name. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: @Krish I got others projects that i receive post requests in Index contreollers.

Comment: ohh... I see some questions related to index controller https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173238/codeigniter-index-controller-routing-problem

Comment: try filling in some data in inputs? still array()?

Comment: You should be using `site_url()` instead of `base_url()`

Answer (score 0):

To check your post data try this.

But make sure your base url is working and htaccess is placed

```
public function busca_vaga() {
    var_dump($this->input->post());
    //OR
    var_dump($this->input->post('busca'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved!

Searching for a solution in .htaccess file, i've identified that my mod_rewrite was disabled in my Linux.

When i turned this mod on, the values where indicated.